# XIB file disappeared but application still works

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xib

I'm using Xcode 4.0.2 and I opened up one of my projects today to find that a .xib file was missing (the .xib that the MainWindow loads). I can't see it in the Finder and it doesn't appear at all in the Xcode window, yet my application still works as if it's there.

Anyone have any idea what might have happened here?

Comment: Please clarify if you right-click on the project in the left pane a click 'Show in Finder', then look in the files in those folders it's not there?

Comment: Nope, not there.  This is very strange..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cmd+Shift+K to clean. Then rebuild and re-run. What exactly is the issue? That its running with the XIB file or where the XIB file went?.. Maybe its not using a XIB file at all (After-all, its not neccessary).

Comment: I need to edit the xib file, I did so only a couple of days ago to add a splash screen, and now its just disappeared.. I cleaned and re-built, still works as it did as if the xib file is there..

Comment: are you deploying on the device or testing in simulator.

Comment: I'm deploying to the simulator

Comment: remove all folders from: <Username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/

then rebuild and re-run.

Comment: Doing that causes a SIGABRT error to occur on this line:   [window addSubview:viewController.view];   In the applicationDidFinishLaunching method?  Does this mean its now missing the XIB file?

Comment: Yes. earlier it was building only from an earlier executable. Is your code in version control? If not, see if the .xib file exists in the directory (not in xcode, in finder). If it doesn't... we'll see if it exists in trash :) .. if it does, move it back and readd it in xcode. if it doesn't..well tough luck. If you are on version control (or if you enabled version control when creating project - you should be safer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you didn't have any custom work in that nib. In your delegate on the line `self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];` it tries to load the ViewController.xib file. Since it can't, it's the same as calling `self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];` which produces a blank generic view.